# How to use the Except in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following that gives me what I want as far the equality of fields in 2 datatables

```
var matched = from s in sendTable.AsEnumerable()
                     join r in recvTable.AsEnumerable() on
                     new { BUS = s.Field<int>("BUS"), 
                           IDENT = s.Field<int>("IDENT"), 
                           STATION = s.Field<int>("STATION"), 
                           REF1 = s.Field<string>("REF1"), 
                           REF2 = s.Field<string>("REF2"),
                           REF3 = s.Field<string>("REF3"),
                           REF4 = s.Field<string>("REF4"),
                           REF5 = s.Field<string>("REF5"),
                           REF6 = s.Field<string>("REF6"),
                           REF7 = s.Field<string>("REF7"),
                           REF8 = s.Field<string>("REF8") } equals
                      new { BUS = r.Field<int>("BUS"), 
                           IDENT = r.Field<int>("IDENT"), 
                           STATION = r.Field<int>("STATION"), 
                           REF1 = r.Field<string>("REF1"), 
                           REF2 = r.Field<string>("REF2"),
                           REF3 = r.Field<string>("REF3"),
                           REF4 = r.Field<string>("REF4"),
                           REF5 = r.Field<string>("REF5"),
                           REF6 = r.Field<string>("REF6"),
                           REF7 = r.Field<string>("REF7"),
                           REF8 = r.Field<string>("REF8") } 
                     select new { Send = s, Receive = r };
```

What I want now is the inequality how do I do this with the Except?

Comment: Could you show an example of input and desired output ?

Comment: Why are you going out of your way to use Linq-To-Objects (via `AsEnumerable` instead of having this done on the db through a Linq query provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) on these fields:

```
var sendIdentityFields = from s in sendTable.AsEnumerable()
                         select new
                         {
                             BUS = s.Field<int>("BUS"),
                             IDENT = s.Field<int>("IDENT"),
                             STATION = s.Field<int>("STATION"),
                             REF1 = s.Field<string>("REF1"),
                             REF2 = s.Field<string>("REF2"),
                             REF3 = s.Field<string>("REF3"),
                             REF4 = s.Field<string>("REF4"),
                             REF5 = s.Field<string>("REF5"),
                             REF6 = s.Field<string>("REF6"),
                             REF7 = s.Field<string>("REF7"),
                             REF8 = s.Field<string>("REF8")
                         };
var receivedIdentityFields = from r in sendTable.AsEnumerable()
                         select new
                         {
                             BUS = r.Field<int>("BUS"),
                             IDENT = r.Field<int>("IDENT"),
                             STATION = r.Field<int>("STATION"),
                             REF1 = r.Field<string>("REF1"),
                             REF2 = r.Field<string>("REF2"),
                             REF3 = r.Field<string>("REF3"),
                             REF4 = r.Field<string>("REF4"),
                             REF5 = r.Field<string>("REF5"),
                             REF6 = r.Field<string>("REF6"),
                             REF7 = r.Field<string>("REF7"),
                             REF8 = r.Field<string>("REF8")
                         };
var sendButNotReceived = sendIdentityFields.Except(receivedIdentityFields);
```

Of course this selects just the anonymous type with these fields and not `DataRows`. If you need to select the `DataRows` of `sendTable` you need to join them with this result on the same fields.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I kinda thought that was what I needed to do to use the except, and I already have a method that takes the result and joins them because I am not really working with a DB as an output, all my table get written to a CSV

Comment: How is not a real question, maybe u no speakee english,  to bad this site has so many pompous windbags stuckupoverflow.com

Comment: @boiler1974: Sometimes question get closed even if they are clear.

Comment: I am sorry for my outburst I have been under alot of pressure, a thousand pardons if I offended anyone  .. Must be the Irish in me